# Getting Merged Datas in mariadb

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariasql

I'm trying to merge datas in mariadb.
I'd like to get only data that have bad result

first you should watch my query I built

There are 3 queries for comparing if it's turned into good data

When round is 1 and it has good as a result, It's not possible to turn into bad next round.
This case is going to have always good or NULL as a result for next round

And

When round is 1 and it has bad as a result, It can turn into good and bad and NULL next round

And

on next round, if it have null as a result, it's going to be still bad result.

```
SELECT name,result,round FROM my_table WHERE round = 1
```

```
╔══════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ name ║ result ║ round ║
╠══════╬════════╬═══════╣
║  A   ║ bad    ║  1    ║
║  B   ║ bad    ║  1    ║
║  C   ║ bad    ║  1    ║
║  D   ║ good   ║  1    ║
╚══════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

```
SELECT name,result,round FROM my_table WHERE round = 2
```

```
╔══════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ name ║ result ║ round ║
╠══════╬════════╬═══════╣
║  A   ║ NULL   ║  2    ║
║  B   ║ NULL   ║  2    ║
║  C   ║ good   ║  2    ║
║  D   ║ NULL   ║  2    ║
╚══════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

```
SELECT name,result,round FROM my_table WHERE round = 3
```

```
╔══════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ name ║ result ║ round ║
╠══════╬════════╬═══════╣
║  A   ║ NULL   ║  3    ║
║  B   ║ good   ║  3    ║
║  C   ║ good   ║  3    ║
║  D   ║ NULL   ║  3    ║
╚══════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

and I want to get result like this:

```
╔══════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ name ║ result ║ round ║
╠══════╬════════╬═══════╣
║  A   ║ bad    ║  3    ║
╚══════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

my point is that I just can search like this

```
SELECT name,result,round FROM my_table WHERE type = 3(last round) and result = 'bad'
```

but you know if it's null, I have to find previous round of what result it have.

and then I'm going to request query again, and if it has NULL as a result again, I have to request the query for previous round. it's going to repeat. I don't think it's a good idea.

if you can understand what I need and what should I do, please let me know better ideas or solutions

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO for your table with the data matched shown outputs. PS. The outputs 2 and 3 does not match the query (`type` in output list but `round` in the output tables).

Comment: @Akina ohh I'm sorry I edited it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```
SELECT name, `bad` result, 3 round
FROM table
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN round = 1 AND result = 'bad' THEN 1 END)
   AND !SUM(CASE WHEN round IN (2,3) AND result = 'good' END)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the most recent non-NULL result to be bad.  You can use aggregation

```
select name
from t
group by name
having max(case when result is not null then round end) = max(case when result = 'Bad' then round end)
```

The `having` clause is getting the most recent round with a result.  It is comparing that round tot he most recent round with a "Bad" result.  When these are equal, then the name is "Bad".

Another approach is to use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by round desc) as seqnum
      from test t
      where result is not null
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and result = 'Bad';
```